# Jquery.Validate.js not working in IE7

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, internet-explorer-7

I am using jquery.validate.js for validation along with jquery-1.9.1.js and it is working fine in all browsers but not in Ie7

Below is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/rwQueryString-1.0.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {

    var ruleSet_default = {
        required: true
    };
    var ruleSet1 = {
        minlength: 2,
        maxlength: 20,
        customvalidation: true
    };
    $.extend(ruleSet1, ruleSet_default); //combines defaults into 1
    var ruleSet2 = {
        email: true
    };
    $.extend(ruleSet2, ruleSet_default); // combines default into 2

    $("#customForm").validate({

        //focusCleanup: true,

        rules: {
            "<%= txtFirstName.UniqueID %>": ruleSet1,
            "<%= txtLastName.UniqueID %>": ruleSet1,
            "<%= txtPosition.UniqueID %>": ruleSet_default,
            "<%= txtEmail.UniqueID %>": ruleSet2,
            "<%= txtCompanyName.UniqueID %>": ruleSet_default,
            "<%= txtCompanyAddress.UniqueID %>": ruleSet_default,
            "<%= txtCity.UniqueID %>": ruleSet_default,
            "<%= txtProvince.UniqueID %>": ruleSet_default,
            "<%= txtCountry.UniqueID %>": ruleSet_default,
            "<%= txtPostalCode.UniqueID %>": ruleSet_default
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).addClass("error");
            $(element).removeClass("OK");
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).removeClass("error");
            $(element).addClass("OK");
        },
        messages: {
            "<%= txtFirstName.UniqueID %>": {
                required: "Please, enter a name",
                minlength: $.format("Keep typing, at least {0} characters required!"),
                maxlength: $.format("Whoa! Maximum {0} characters allowed!")
            },
            "<%= txtLastName.UniqueID %>": {
                required: "Please, enter last name",
                minlength: $.format("Keep typing, at least {0} characters required!"),
                maxlength: $.format("Whoa! Maximum {0} characters allowed!")
            },
            "<%= txtPosition.UniqueID %>": "Please, enter your position",
            "<%= txtEmail.UniqueID %>": {
                required: "Please, enter your email",
                email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com"
            },
            "<%= txtCompanyName.UniqueID %>": "Please, enter your company name",
            "<%= txtCompanyAddress.UniqueID %>": "Please, enter your company address",
            "<%= txtCity.UniqueID %>": "Please, enter your city",
            "<%= txtProvince.UniqueID %>": "Please, enter your province",
            "<%= txtCountry.UniqueID %>": "Please, enter your country",
            "<%= txtPostalCode.UniqueID %>": "Please, enter your zip code"
        }

    });
    $.validator.addMethod("customvalidation",
            function (value, element) {
                return /^[A-Za-z\d=#$%@_ -]+$/.test(value);
            },
    "Sorry, no special characters allowed"
    );
});
</script>
```

I got this error while try to run this in IE7

```
0x80020003 - JavaScript runtime error: Member not found. in jquery-1.9.1.js
```

but when I comment out jquery-validate.js code then jquery-1.9.1.js doesn't produce any problem in IE7.

Please help because I am stuck here for last few days.

Thanks

Comment: are you finding this issue with getsetattribute in jquery core js file ?

Comment: Please only show the _rendered_ code when asking about client-side code... in other words, we don't need to see what you uploaded to the server.  We need to see what the browser is running.  That includes the relevant HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery 1.9 and newer versions don't support IE6/7/8, well, it may work but there is no guarantee.

Use jquery 1.8.3 it supports old browsers including Opera 9